# How to check if MySQL returns null/empty?

Tags: php, mysql

In DB I have a table with a field called `fk_ownerID`. By default, when I add a new table row, the `fk_ownerID` is empty. In Toad for MySQL, this is shown as `{null}`. If `fk_ownerID` is given a value, and I later remove this value, I set `fk_ownerID = ""`.

Now, I have the following code:

```
$result = $dal->getRowByValue('tableName','id', $_POST['myID']);

// Check to see if any rows where returned
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $ownerID = $row["fk_ownerID"];    
  }
}
```

Now the variable $ownerID should have a number, or not. But I'm unsure how to check this. Currently I'm doing this:

```
if ( (strlen($ownerID) == 0) || ($ownerID == '0') || ($ownerID == 'null') )
```

But I'm pretty sure only one of these tests should be necessary.

What is the best way to check if a row field is empty or null?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use empty() and/or is_null()

http://www.php.net/empty http://www.php.net/is_null

Empty alone will achieve your current usage, is_null would just make more control possible if you wanted to distinguish between a field that is null and a field that is empty.

Comment: So I have to use empty() AND is_null()?

Comment: ok.... empty() should do :) --> Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value. 

The following things are considered to be empty: 
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Comment: I reckon that `is_null()` is safer, because if a variable has a zero value it's still considered `empty()`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use is_null() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php : in the comments :

> mdufour at gmail dot com
> 20-Aug-2008 04:31
> Testing for a NULL field/column returned by a mySQL query.
>
> Say you want to check if field/column “foo” from a given row of the table “bar” when > returned by a mySQL query is null.
> You just use the “is_null()” function:

```
[connect…]
$qResult=mysql_query("Select foo from bar;");
while ($qValues=mysql_fetch_assoc($qResult))
     if (is_null($qValues["foo"]))
         echo "No foo data!";
     else
         echo "Foo data=".$qValues["foo"];
[…]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

will return no. of records selected by select query.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget the === operator when you're working with numbers that could mean null or 0 or return some form of false or null that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I agree, should have been left as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( (strlen($ownerID) == 0) || ($ownerID == '0') || (empty($ownerID )) )
```

if **$ownerID** is **NULL** it will be triggered by the **empty()** test

https://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 0):

If your datatype in your mysql database is an auto-increment primary key, then you can't use `is_null()` you must use `empty()` or in code, it would be `if (empty($id)) {`

Answer (score -6):

Suppose

```
$row=mysql_fetch_row($rc)
and if you want to check if row[8] is null then do
$field=$row[8];
   if($field)
echo "";
else
 echo "";
```