# MySQL 'NULL' On PHP IF Statement : How To Write It?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if mysql returns null/empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693428/how-to-check-if-mysql-returns-null-empty)

I have SQL command (LEFT JOIN between 2 tables) with result 'NULL' or '0'. And now I want to create PHP condition like this :

```
if ($rowSearch['Approved'] == NULL)
```

but it failed... then I tried this one

```
if ($rowSearch['Approved'] == 'NULL')
```

also failed... PHP always skip that statement. how to write PHP IF statement for this? thanks before.

Comment: does `if(isset($rowSearch['Approved']))` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to distinguish between `NULL`, `""`, `False`, and `0`, then you need to use a strict comparison `===`. Or you can use `is_null()`. [The table on this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( empty($rowSearch['Approved']) && $rowSearch['Approved'] !== 0 )
```

Comment: This will also be true if the field contains `0` however.

Comment: `empty` will also return `true` if the value is `0` though.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté updated to reflect that

Comment: @ThiefMaster understandable confusion. I appreciate the reconsideration :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare with `===`

```
if ($rowSearch['Approved'] === null)
```