# Not able to view NULL values from MYsql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains some Role_codes
Find below table

[image]

I'm able to get all distinct role_code from the table but in the case NULL the result is blank.

Below code for the same:

```
    <?php

    if ($role_code === 'BOB')
        {
        $sql = "SELECT distinct role_code FROM `create_user`";
        $result = $pdoConn->query($sql);
        if ($result !== false)
            {
            echo "<div class='w3-container w3-responsive w3-round w3-padding-
            large' style='width:95%;margin:10px;'>";
        echo " <h4 class='w3-text-indigo'>Admin please select role to view 
           record.</h4> 
<select id='view_record' name='view_record' class='w3-input w3-light-grey' style='width:90%'><option value='select Role'>Select Role</option>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                $role_id = $row["role_code"];
                echo "<option  value=$role_id>" . $row["role_code"] . "</option>";
                }

            echo "</select></div>";
            }
        }
```

the above code is returning all the unique values but in the case Null it is returning blank.

Comment: Your sample table doesn't actually have a `role_id` column.  Can you show that to us?

Comment: Off the top of my head, use `COALESCE(role_id, 'something')` if you want to show a placeholder value instead of `NULL`, which appears to be coming up empty.

Comment: even if value or $row['role_id'] is null it will be converted to the empty string, because you use concatenation, check var_dump(''.NULL); - you will always have a string, - empty string )

Comment: In your while loop, try `var_dump`ing the `$row` variable. if it shows `null`s in the output, then you need to look for a solution in php. if not, look for mysql side solutions.

Comment: you want show Null values too . is it ?

Comment: @JYoThI : Yes, i want to show null values too

Comment: SELECT distinct (COALESCE(role_code, 'NULL')) FROM `create_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concept of null in HTML content.  When you `echo` `null` in PHP, you get an empty string.  I would suggest changing your while statement to this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $role_id = $row["role_id"];
  echo "<option value='" . (is_null($role_id) ? "null" . $role_id) . "'>" . $row["role_id"] . "</option>";
}
```

...which then sets the value of the `option` to the string `"null"`.  Then, when receiving the data back on server-side after a form submission, you can convert back to `null` like this:

```
$role_id = ($_POST['view_record'] === 'null' ? null : (int)$_POST['view_record']);
```

Doing it this way means you preserve not only `null` values back and forth, but you also cater for `role_id` = `0`, and are converting the client data from string (which is what all HTML posted variables are) to the correct database type.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in ur code

```
if(is_null($result['role_code']))
{
   echo "<option value='0'>Null</option>";
}else{
   echo "<option value='1'>Result...</option>";
}
```

and see 
[How to check if mysql returns null/empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693428/how-to-check-if-mysql-returns-null-empty)

and 
[PHP Check for NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for `NULL` value :

```
if($variable === NULL) {...}
```

NOT

```
if($variable === 'NULL') {...}
```

Because `NULL` is not a string if you check NULL value as like other string value like `NULL` then the condition will not check for `NULL` value.